# Sqlalchemy complains that foreign key doesn't exist but actually it exists

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following models:

```
class Look(Base):
  __tablename__ = "looks"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  url = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)

class Similarity(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'similarities'
  __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('look_id_small', 'look_id_big'),)
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  look_id_small = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('looks.id'), nullable=False)
  look_id_big = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('looks.id'), nullable=False)
```

When I am running this code:

```
try:
  with session.begin_nested():
    similarity = Similarity()
    similarity.look_id_small, similarity.look_id_big = look_id1, look_id2
    session.add(similarity)
    session.commit()
except Exception, e:
  logging.error(e)
  print "look_id1: %s, look_id2: %s" % (look_id1, look_id2)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
2013-01-19 04:55:42,974 ERROR Foreign key associated with column 'similarities.look_id_small' could not find table 'looks' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
look_id1: 217137, look_id2: 283579
```

so I tried looking for these values in pgsql and they do exist!

```
giordano=# SELECT * FROM looks WHERE id = 217137 or id = 283579;
   id   |                      url                      | title | image_url | 
--------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+-----------+
 217137 | http://foo.com                                |       |           |     
 283579 | http://baz.com                                |       |           |
(2 rows)
```

I have spent the whole night trying to figure this out.

Some clues:

1. I am only getting these errors on certain values.
2. I don't think having double foreignkeys on the same table will result in an issue.

Anyone?

EDIT:

```
giordano=# \d+ looks 
                                              Table "public.looks"
    Column     |       Type        |                     Modifiers                      | Storage  | Description 
---------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------
 id            | integer           | not null default nextval('looks_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    | 
 url           | character varying | not null                                           | extended | 
Indexes:
    "looks_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "looks_url_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (url)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "similarities" CONSTRAINT "similarities_look_id_big_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (look_id_big) REFERENCES looks(id)
    TABLE "similarities" CONSTRAINT "similarities_look_id_small_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (look_id_small) REFERENCES looks(id)
Has OIDs: no

giordano=# \d+ similarities
                                             Table "public.similarities"
    Column     |       Type       |                         Modifiers                         | Storage | Description 
---------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------
 id            | integer          | not null default nextval('similarities_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   | 
 look_id_small | integer          | not null                                                  | plain   | 
 look_id_big   | integer          | not null                                                  | plain   | 
Indexes:
    "similarities_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "similarities_look_id_small_look_id_big_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (look_id_small, look_id_big)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "similarities_look_id_big_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (look_id_big) REFERENCES looks(id)
    "similarities_look_id_small_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (look_id_small) REFERENCES looks(id)
Has OIDs: no
```

EDIT

After turning on my postgresql statements, this is what I am seeing:

```
LOG:  statement: BEGIN
LOG:  statement: select version()
LOG:  statement: select current_schema()
LOG:  statement: show transaction isolation level
LOG:  statement: SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
LOG:  statement: SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
LOG:  statement: BEGIN
LOG:  statement: DECLARE "c_10dfc08d0_1L" CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR SELECT feedbacks.id AS feedbacks_id, feedbacks.user_id AS feedbacks_user_id, feedbacks.look_id AS feedbacks_look_id 
    FROM feedbacks 
     LIMIT 500
LOG:  statement: FETCH FORWARD 1 FROM "c_10dfc08d0_1L"
LOG:  statement: FETCH FORWARD 5 FROM "c_10dfc08d0_1L"
LOG:  statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "c_10dfc08d0_1L"
LOG:  statement: FETCH FORWARD 20 FROM "c_10dfc08d0_1L"
LOG:  statement: FETCH FORWARD 50 FROM "c_10dfc08d0_1L"
LOG:  statement: FETCH FORWARD 100 FROM "c_10dfc08d0_1L"
LOG:  statement: FETCH FORWARD 250 FROM "c_10dfc08d0_1L"
LOG:  statement: FETCH FORWARD 500 FROM "c_10dfc08d0_1L"
LOG:  statement: FETCH FORWARD 1000 FROM "c_10dfc08d0_1L"
LOG:  statement: CLOSE "c_10dfc08d0_1L"
LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
```

I am not seeing any "INSERTS". Why?

Comment: The data model looks OK. Try to dig up the generated query (maybe from the postgres log?)

Comment: Does this help? 

ERROR look_id1: 34816, look_id2: 283143
2013-01-19 06:10:25,559 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_2
2013-01-19 06:10:25,560 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2013-01-19 06:10:25,561 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_2
2013-01-19 06:10:25,561 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}

Comment: No, that does not help. Try to find the generated SQL query. You may need to crank up your postgres logging level to log all statements (or only the failed ones)

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://codeinthehole.com/writing/configuring-logging-for-postgresapp/

Comment: try setting `log_statement = 'all'` in your postgres.conf and rerun the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out using ForeignKey(Look.id) did the trick!!

According to argonholm from #sqllachemy:

18:25 agronholm: I would have to guess that the syntax for text-form table references is not what you expected 18:26 agronholm: maybe ForeignKey('Look.id') would also work?